# An obscure corner of the Haskell Report

Tags: haskell, syntax

Section 5.2 of the Haskell 2010 Report deals with module export lists. At one point, it [says](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch5.html#x11-1000005.2):

> Entities in an export list may be named as follows:
>
> 1. A value, field name, or class method, whether declared in the module body or imported, may be named by giving the name of the value as a *qvarid*, which must be in scope. Operators should be enclosed in parentheses to turn them into *qvarids*.
>
> ...

But, uh... am I missing something? Because according to the Syntax Reference in [Chapter 10](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch10.html#x17-17500010):

> *qvarid* → [ *monid* . ] *varid*
>
> *varid* → ( *small* { *small* | *large* | *digit* | ' })

So in which universe does putting an operator in brackets turn it into a *qvarid*? It looks to me like an operator is clearly a *varsym* (or maybe *qvarsym*).

Does anybody know what's going on here? I mean, *clearly* Haskell definitely supports writing operators in an export list, but the syntax description in the Report doesn't appear to make sense...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wait, hold up... According to the Control-Free Syntax given in section 10.5:

> export → *qvar* | *qtycon* ... | *qtycls* ... | `module` *monid*
>
> ...
>
> *var* → *varid* | `(` *varsym* `)`
>
> *qvar* → *qvarid* | `(` *qvarsym* `)`

So it seems that it's **not** a *qvarid*, it's supposed to be a *qvar*. So it's just a typo, I guess? Is there a process for having such things fixed in the official report?

Comment: Start with the email lists. Maybe haskell@haskell.org?

Comment: I think not `haskell@haskell.org`, that's mostly for announcements, and fairly low volume. I'm not sure what's the "correct" place, but `haskell-cafe@haskell.org` is for general discussion, so it shouldn't be *too* out of place there.

Comment: Oh, found [on the wiki](https://wiki.haskell.org/Language_and_library_specification): "If you find a mistake in the report, please send it to the [haskell-prime mailing list](http://www.haskell.org/mailman/listinfo/haskell-prime) (you have to register first), or send it directly to one of the current committee members."